# Prevent cell value changing when performing reprojection in r

Tags: r, project, raster

I have a raster tif file. Its projection is WGS84: epsg=4326. Cell values are integers: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13.
I used the following codes to change its projection to NAD83/BC Albers: epsg=3005

```
LU_AOI<- projectRaster(LU_AOI, crs = crs("+init=EPSG:3005"))
```

My problem is that when I change the projection, cell values change to floating values such as 1.65, 2.3333, 3.87, etc.

I need to keep the same integer cell values. How can I prevent the cell values from changing when I change the projection of my raster tif file in RStudio?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed the calculation method to the nearest neighbor.

```
LU_AOI<- projectRaster(LU_AOI, crs = crs("+init=EPSG:3005"), method="ngb")
```